# For each column of a dataframe, add mean and standard deviation in the last two rows

Tags: python, pandas, mean

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(123)

data = rng.random((10,2))
foo = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

I want to add two rows to `foo`, the first one containing (for each column) the mean of rows from 0 to 9, and the second one containing (again, separately for each column) the standard deviation of rows from 0 to 9. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option :

```
out = pd.concat(
        [foo, foo.describe().loc[["mean", "std"]]]
        # with an optional chain `.reset_index(drop=True)`
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

             A         B
0     0.696469  0.286139
1     0.226851  0.551315
2     0.719469  0.423106
3     0.980764  0.684830
4     0.480932  0.392118
5     0.343178  0.729050
6     0.438572  0.059678
7     0.398044  0.737995
8     0.182492  0.175452
9     0.531551  0.531828
mean  0.499832  0.457151
std   0.243457  0.233585
```

Comment: It works! Can you please improve the answer by explaining why we need double square brackets in the call to `loc`? `loc[["mean", "std"]]`

Comment: We're using here square brackets (*i.e a list*) in [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) because we're selecting more than a single row (`mean` and `std`) in the DataFrame returned by [`describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) (*read more here* : [*Different choices for indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing))

Comment: ok, I would have added that in the answer rather than in the comments, but as you prefer.